# Cronjob stopped to run

Tags: linux, cron

I am working on a Linux VM and I have a cron job running every day at 11:35 P.M running a python script that call an API and export that data on Google Cloud Storage.

I had daily exports in my Google Storage bucket at 11:35 every day such as the following file exported on February 10th at 11:35 p.m. What I am getting when I am typing  `crontab -l` on my VM is:

```
35 22 * * * /home/worker/xxxx/yyyy/launch.sh
```

**launch.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

BASE_PROJECT="/home/worker/xxxx/yyyy"

export PYTHONPATH="${BASE_PROJECT}"
export GOOGLE_USER_CREDENTIALS="${BASE_PROJECT}/credentials_red.json"
export PIPENV_PIPFILE="${BASE_PROJECT}/ingestion/Pipfile"

pipenv run python "${BASE_PROJECT}/ingestion/main.py"
```

**files on GCS:**

[image]
**Issue**

My files were exported daily at 11:35 every day since December until February 14th, since then, 0 files were exported to Google Cloud Storage. I made some changes on my `ingestion/main.py` February 14th, it may be the reason but I would like to know what was the issue if possible. The first thing I have done today is to restaure the `ingestion/main.py` version from < February 14th. What else I have done is:

1. The `ingestion/main.py` script is calling an external API. I did call that same API today from my desktop with the credentials stored on the VM to see if the issue was about credentials. It is not the issue as I am able to get the data back.
2. After that, I decided to run my `launch.sh` directly from my VM and it actually worked as all of my files were imported on Google Cloud Storage (I already restored the older version of `ingestion/main.py` when I ran it.

I am still unsure about what cause that issue and I run `sudo grep CRON var/log/syslog` but there is only a couple of lines. Is there a way to get more informations about why my cronjob did not run?

Comment: Thanks, fixed it. I think I found the issue in the `mailù there is error logs

Answer (score 1):

Output (normal or error), if any is sent by mail to the linux user running the script.

If your VM is not configured to send mail broadly, or if you didn't setup a `.forward` to relay mail from linux to internet, maybe mail are still here,
try `mail` from command line.

If you like self spamming, just add

```
MAILTO=me@exemple.com
```

as first line of your crontab.

Answer (score 1):

Make a change to your `crontab` to *redirect* any output from the script to a logfile in your home directory (or somewhere else if you have the privileges and wish to do so). Since your `cron` job is running in a *non-interactive shell*, `stdin` and `stdout` go to the "bit bucket" (`/dev/null`) - which is not helpful if you have an error.

Try this revised `crontab` entry:

```
35 22 * * * /home/worker/xxxx/yyyy/launch.sh >> /home/worker/cronlog.txt 2>&1
```